# Searching for OCR that works well with non Latin characters(mainly Hebrew and Arabic)

Tags: windows, python, java, c#, ocr

Is there any good Hebrew OCR **API/library** (preferably free but not necessary)

the text is printed so no need for hand-writing

An Example for an image I want to parse
[image]

The Program language is non-relevant but preferably C#/Java/Python

I have tried the following libraries

1. [tesseract](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract)
2. [IronOCR](https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/ocr/)
3. [Goolge Vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision/)

But all Insufficient results

Comment: Clarification: Are you looking for an _application_, or an API/library to incorporate into your own code?

Comment: [This google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=hebrew+ocr) brings up some other possibilities.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin API/library. edited the question